# How do I read variable from .env file GatsbyJS, React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, environment-variables, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby.js to build a small portfolio and I'm using Instagram API to display my pictures on a page `./src/pages/gallery.js`.

I created an `.env` file in the root directory and inside it I have the instagram's access token. I read somewhere on here that for React, the environment variable has to start with REACT_APP. So I have it like `REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN=534R34QLJ.1JLJKL..`. So how do you use this variable in the URL `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=?

I tried:

`var ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN;
var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN;`

The variable `url` is passed in this function:

`fetchPhotos(){
   request
     .get(url)
     .then((res) => {
       this.setState({
         photos: res.body.data
       })
     })
    }`

I keep getting undefined. And I tried different ways to append it, but after debugging, I found out that the variable ACCESS_TOKEN is empty and not reading the variable in the `.env` file, and it works fine if I hardcode the access token in the URL, but I don't want to make it publicly available obviously. So what am I missing?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem **or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what's not clear in my question? I'm asking how I get the variable in .env file, and I showed you the code and how I tried and how it didn't work and my thought process. Now I'm stuck. So what else do you want me to include?? The desired behavior is to get the variable from the .env file which clearly I couldn't do it and that is why I'm asking this question. I have looked and tried different things and still didn't work. Now I ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using template literals to add it to your url.

```
var url = `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/? 
access_token=${process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN}`;
```

Make sure to use backticks instead of quotation marks.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. That's what I get in the console: 
GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=undefined 400

Comment: It might be because it needs to be a string. Try wrapping the api key/access token in your .env file with single quotes.

Comment: It looks like in their docs it says to name env files for development and production like .env.development or .env.production https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/ Try changing the .env filename and see if that works